# java how can we know if field is array of inner classes?

Tags: java, reflection

I read this tutorial:
http://jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/two_side_notes_about_arrays

But still cant figure out how to distinguish between primitive, arrays and classes (in reflection)

For example:
I have the following class:

```
class MainClass {

    public MainClass() {
        memberSubClass = new SubClass();
        arrayMemberSubClass = new SubClass[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            arrayMemberSubClass[i] = new SubClass();
        }
        array_int_member = new int[5];
    }

    class SubClass {
        public int x;
        public short y;
    }

    public SubClass memberSubClass;
    public SubClass[] arrayMemberSubClass;
    public int int_member;
    public int[] array_int_member;
}
```

And I have the folloing method (in other class):

```
public void doSometing(Object obj) {

    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {    
        if (field.getType().isArray()) {
                if (field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
                    logger.debug(field.getName() + " is array of primitives");
                } else {
                    logger.debug(field.getName() + " is array of classes");
                }       
            }   
            else {
                if (field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
                    logger.debug(field.getName() + " is primitives");
                } else {
                    logger.debug(field.getName() + " is class");
                }       
            }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
0 [main] DEBUG Logic  - memberSubClass is class
1 [main] DEBUG Logic  - arrayMemberSubClass is array of classes
1 [main] DEBUG Logic  - int_member is primitives
1 [main] DEBUG Logic  - array_int_member is array of classes
```

I expected to get the follwing output:

```
0 [main] DEBUG Logic  - memberSubClass is class
1 [main] DEBUG Logic  - arrayMemberSubClass is array of classes
1 [main] DEBUG Logic  - int_member is primitives
1 [main] DEBUG Logic  - array_int_member is array of primitives
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

From the page you cited:

```
One thing I think was missing in the post is how to get the type of the array elements using reflection. This can be done using the getComponentType() method:

Boolean[] b = new Boolean[5];
Class<?> theTypeOfTheElements = b.getClass().getComponentType();
System.out.println(theTypeOfTheElements.getName());
```

Comment: mmm it does help much. Beacuse the array can be (Integer, Boolean, Short...  or other inner defined class).. so Do I need to check all the types ?

Comment: if (field.getType().isArray()) {
                
                Class<?> theTypeOfTheElements = field.getClass().getComponentType();    
return null ... :(